# How to display a particular data on new page from list of records retrieved from database displayed on first page?

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a php page where list of people are displayed from the database. Now what I want to do is when I click a particular Person's data from the list it should redirect to another page where all the details of that person are present.Is it possible to do so?

I have two pages:
list.php :- Here the list of people is displayed from database in small cards using bootstrap.The card includes some data like pid,pname.
Details.php :-
This page is where all the details of a person should display(e.g. pid,pname,pno,paddress,etc)

I tried using onclick function on that cards. It worked too but I have no idea how to get the data of that particular person clicked on the next page?

lists.php :-
`

```
<?php
   include 'config.php';
   $sql = "SELECT p_id,p_name,p_adddate FROM sampletable";
   $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
   {
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    { 
?>
<div class="card" onclick="window.location.href='details.php'">
   <div class="card-body">
    <?php echo <strong>".$row["p_id"].$row["p_name"]."</strong>
<span style='float:right;'>Date : ".$row["p_adddate"]."</span>";?>
    </div>
</div>
```

details.php :-

```
<?php
   include 'config.php';
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM sampletable" WHERE p_id="HELP WHAT TO DO!!";
   $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
   {
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    { 
 ?>
<div class="col">
ID: <?php echo $row['p_id']; ?>Name: <?php echo $row['p_name']; ?>
No: <?php echo $row['p_no']; ?>Address :<?php echo $row['p_add']; ?>
</div>
```

When I click a particular person on lists.php , I expect to display that particular person's all data on the details page. 
I tried storing id in session, but on next page the id stored in session is the id of the latest record in database.I cant get a specific id. Please help...Thanks in advance

Comment: try to pass the id to the details.php like: onclick="<?php echo 'window.location.href="details.php?id='.$row['p_id'].'" ?>" then just catch it in the details.php, just make sure to add some validations if you don't want everyone to access every person

Comment: You said just catch it in the details.php. But what do you exactly mean by that?Sorry I am just a beginner so I didn't understood that.

Comment: replace the "HELP WHAT TO DO!!" with $_GET['id'], this will get the parameter, be aware not to trust users inputs and escape special characters

Comment: Ok...thanks for the help.